# How to get access a variable defined in a Coroutine from another class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine, path-finding, game-development

Well the thing is, Im working on pathfinding with a tutorial I found online, and the waypoints are getting added in the coroutine, and I need to access the variable "currentwaypoint" which is defined in the coroutine

```
 public IEnumerator FollowPath()
{
      Vector3 currentWayPoint = path[0];
   

        while (true)
        {
            if (transform.position == currentWayPoint)
            {
                targetIndex++;


                if (targetIndex >= path.Length)
                {
                    targetIndex = 0;


                    path = new Vector3[0];

                    reached = true;
                 
                    yield break;
                }
                reached = false;
                currentWayPoint = path[targetIndex];
                lastDir = (currentWayPoint - transform.position).normalized;

            }                
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, currentWayPoint, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, GetAngle(currentWayPoint));
            fov.SetAngle(GetAngle(currentWayPoint));


        yield return null;
        }
```

but when I do is as adding the "lastDir" variable which is defined outside the Coroutine, it returns only 0,0,0 which is its default value I guess.

So what I need is to access this variables value as it updates in the loop

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you send full script?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Define it in class level instead:

```
// The value you actually store and update
private Vector3 currentWayPoint;

// A public Read-Only property for everyone else
public Vector3 CurrentWayPoint => currentWayPoint;

public IEnumerator FollowPath()
{
    currentWayPoint = path[0];
   
    while (true)
    {
        if (transform.position == currentWayPoint)
        {
            targetIndex++;

            if (targetIndex >= path.Length)
            {
                targetIndex = 0;

                path = new Vector3[0];

                reached = true;
                 
                yield break;
            }

            reached = false;
            currentWayPoint = path[targetIndex];
            lastDir = (currentWayPoint - transform.position).normalized;
        }    
        
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, currentWayPoint, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, GetAngle(currentWayPoint));
        fov.SetAngle(GetAngle(currentWayPoint));

        yield return null;
    }
}
```

so another script would go

```
var waypoint = someObject.GetComponent<YourClass>().CurrentWayPoint;
```

Comment: Thanks, seems I messed up the problems :D