# How to access a variable defined inside a Coroutine from another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, coroutine

As the title suggests, I am trying to access two variables declared within a coroutine from another class in order to store them in a .csv file. I have followed this thread [How to get access a variable defined in a Coroutine from another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63137514/how-to-get-access-a-variable-defined-in-a-coroutine-from-another-class) but to no avail (both variables return (0,0,0), like they are not being populated).

My code:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Unity.XR.PXR;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class ET_RayCast : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector]
    public static float timerTarget, timerDistractor;

    [HideInInspector]
    public static string hitObjectName;

    [SerializeField]
    private Text targetTimeTxt, distractorTimeTxt, gazeDirTxt, gazeOriginTxt, currentFixatedObj;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject point;

    Matrix4x4 matrix;
    bool istargetFixated = false;
    bool rTriggerValue;
    Vector3 RealOriginOffset, DirectionOffset;

    [HideInInspector]
    public Vector3 realOriginOffset => RealOriginOffset;
    [HideInInspector]
    public Vector3 directionOffset => DirectionOffset;
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(EyeRaycast(0.04f));
    }
    IEnumerator EyeRaycast(float steptime)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (Camera.main)
            {
                matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(Camera.main.transform.position, Camera.main.transform.rotation, Vector3.one);
            }
            else
            {
                matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity, Vector3.one);
            }
            bool result = (PXR_EyeTracking.GetCombineEyeGazePoint(out Vector3 Origin) && PXR_EyeTracking.GetCombineEyeGazeVector(out Vector3 Direction));
            PXR_EyeTracking.GetCombineEyeGazePoint(out Origin);
            PXR_EyeTracking.GetCombineEyeGazeVector(out Direction);
            var RealOriginOffset = matrix.MultiplyPoint(Origin);
            var DirectionOffset = matrix.MultiplyVector(Direction);
            Ray ray = new Ray(RealOriginOffset, DirectionOffset);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (result)
            {
                gazeDirTxt.text = DirectionOffset.ToString("F3");
                gazeOriginTxt.text = RealOriginOffset.ToString("F3");

                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 20f))
                {
                    currentFixatedObj.text = hit.collider.gameObject.name;
                    hitObjectName = hit.collider.gameObject.name;

                    if (hit.collider.CompareTag("target"))
                    {
                        timerTarget += Time.deltaTime;
                        targetTimeTxt.text = timerTarget.ToString("F3");
                        point.transform.position = hit.point;
                        istargetFixated = true;

                        if (istargetFixated && (InputDevices.GetDeviceAtXRNode(XRNode.RightHand).TryGetFeatureValue(CommonUsages.triggerButton, out rTriggerValue) && rTriggerValue))
                        {
                            timerTarget = 0f;
                            timerDistractor = 0f;
                            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
                        }
                    }
                    if (hit.collider.CompareTag("Untagged"))
                    {
                        timerDistractor += Time.deltaTime;
                        distractorTimeTxt.text = timerDistractor.ToString("F3");
                        point.transform.position = hit.point;
                    }
                }
            }
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(steptime);
        }
    }
}
```

The variables that I would like to access from another script are `var RealOriginOffset` and   `var DirectionOffset`. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove `var` in that two lines.

Comment: Man, you are a legend. It worked! OMG

Answer (score 1):

Convert workflow to `Asynchronous` programming, With this method you can define, for example, two variables within a time-dependent function.

```cs
public async Task<(Vector3, Vector3)> EyeRaycast(float stepTime)
{
    var x = Vector3.one;
    var y = Vector3.forward;
    while (!Input.anyKey)
    {
        Debug.Log("New Loop Start");

        await Task.Delay((int) stepTime*1000);
    }
    return (x, y);
}
```

And so get it after the changes.

```cs
public async Task Start()
{
    var Result = await EyeRaycast(1);
    
    Debug.Log(Result); // ((1.0, 1.0, 1.0), (0.0, 0.0, 1.0))
}
```